# Вызов функции родительского окна в дочернем JS

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Есть родительское окно, в котором через window.open() создаётся дочернее окно с генерируемым контентом. Так же есть функция save(), которая сохраняет в файл всю html страницу. Если написать так:

```
var load_window = window.open(url,"Скачивание документа","status=no,location=no,directories=no,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=620,height=440"); 
 load_window.focus();
 load_window.onload = function() {
    var html = load_window.document.documentElement.innerHTML; 
    var blob = new Blob([html], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"});
    window.saveAs(blob, 'print.doc');
 };
```

то поверх родительского окна откроется дочернее, но скачивание документа пойдёт в родительском. Нужно, чтобы скачивание документа тоже шло в дочернем. load_window.saveAs(...) не работает, window.open.saveAs(...) тоже - ни в том, ни в другом случае документ не скачивается вовсе - ни в дочернем, ни в родительском окне

Comment: _load_window.saveAs(...) не работает_ - почему ты думаешь, что не работает?

Comment: @Grundy Потому что пробовал, логично же

Comment: А почему решил, что не работает?

Comment: @Grundy Потому что не скачивается. То есть ни в родительском, ни в дочернем

Comment: добавь это в вопрос.

Comment: а `this.saveAs(...)`?

Comment: Спасибо большое, this.window.saveAs(...) помогло